# How to associate existing product options with multiple products using Bigcommerce v3 API?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, bigcommerce

I am creating products on my bigcommerce store using v3 API where I am passing option_display_name and label of options with variants in body parameters. But due to this duplicate product options are getting created. I can see multiple product options in my store with same option display name. Can you please suggest how we can associate same product options with multiple products using Bigcommerce v3 API?

I am passing following body parameters in request:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "weight": 0,
  "width": 0,
  "depth": 0,
  "height": 0,
  "price": 0,
  "cost_price": 0,
  "retail_price": 0,
  "sale_price": 0,
  "tax_class_id": 0,
  "product_tax_code": "string",
  "categories": [
    0
  ],
  "brand_id": 0,  
  "search_keywords": "string",
  "page_title": "string",
  "meta_keywords": [
    "string"
  ],
  "meta_description": "string",
  "variants": [
    {
      "cost_price": 0,
      "price": 0,
      "weight": 0,
      "purchasing_disabled": true,
      "purchasing_disabled_message": "string",
      "image_url": "string",
      "upc": "string",
      "inventory_level": 0,
      "inventory_warning_level": 0,
      "bin_picking_number": "string",
      "product_id": 0,
      "sku": "string",
      "option_values": [
        {
          "option_display_name": "string",
          "label": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]" and linked pages. Showing us the data is only part of what we need. We also need to see the minimal code that will duplicate the problem. Code, like a picture, is worth 10,000 words.

Comment: For V3, you associate options to products directly and those options are particular to those products so associating an existing option to another product doesn’t really make sense

Comment: @Alyss I created around 4500 products in my bigcommerce store using v3 API and it created around 7900 product options which were listed under "Product Options" menu. I suspect that it might break big commerce at some point if I create large number of products. What do you think?

Comment: @Alyss Those 7900 options are redundant. There are 3 options for each product and those 3 options are same for all products and are getting created for every product.

Comment: BigCommerce can support more than 7900 options. They are redundant, but BigCommerce will be working on updating the UI to conform more closely the v3 API model.